# Problems booting Ubuntu USB

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I have a (with Ubuntu,) bootable USB. But, if I boot to it, its automaticly boot to GRUB with no errors. It says;

```
Loading GRUB...
Welcome To GRUB!
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I`m created the USB from Rufus 3.22.2009.

The Ubuntu version is 22.04.3 LTE (amd64).

You can say questions, but please help!
Thanks.

```
PC:LG
MODEL:A520
Ubuntu Desktop
Rufus 3.22.2009 - FAT32

ISO file=Not Corrupted
USB`s total capacity=14.6 GB
Processor=2 GHz, 4cores
RAM=4 GB
Disk Space=200gb
Internet=Usable
```

If you want some more informations, please say.

Comment: We need more information in order to help. Otherwise we can only guess. So please tell us about the computer: brand name and model; tell us which version and flavour of Ubuntu you are trying (Ubuntu Desktop or Server? Which version (22.04.x LTS or some other version?) Please tell us also how you made the USB drive bootable: Which tool and method? Did you check that the downloaded iso file was good (check with `sha256sum`)?

Comment: I added the more informations. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the details :-) I have a few suggestions what to try: 1. Please try with cloning: Select **dd-mode** in Rufus. Cloned drives boot well in most (but not all) PC computers; 2. There might be problems with the nvidia card. Add the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` in the grub menu before continuing booting; 3. It might work better with a light-weight flavour of Ubuntu: Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Comment: Sooooo thanks, i gonna try the 1 :-)

Comment: Hey @sudodus , now im getting this error,;


ZSTD-compressed data is corrupt 


--System halted

Please help me again!

Comment: When (where in the process) do you get that error message? When running Rufus, when trying to boot from the USB drive, during installation or when trying to boot the installed system?

Comment: I got this error on (in GRUB, software selecting screen) select only "Ubuntu" and waiting one minute later, that error appears.

Comment: Furthermore, 1. which kind of Ubuntu is it, Desktop or Server? 2. Which kind of file system did you select? 3. Grub of the live system booted from USB or grub of the installed system?

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop , FAT32

Comment: FAT32 indicates that you are talking about problems when trying to boot 'live' from the USB drive. Is that correct?

Comment: Did you try **dd-mode** of Rufus? It should bring a drive where the main partition has an iso9660 file system.

Comment: How did you check that the download was good? Did you run `sha256` and check versus the uploaded checksum?

Comment: I didint understand what do you mean, but was I supposed to use NTFS?

Comment: Okay I am now going to run sha256.

Comment: Yes, I am used dd mode of Rufus.

Comment: sha256 codes: a435f6f393dda581172490eda9f683c32e495158a780b5a1de422ee77d98e909

Comment: No, not NTFS. When running Rufus in dd-mode, everything is overwritten by the cloning operation, and the the main partition will copy the iso9660 file system from the iso file. There will be a very small FAT32 file system, but no NTFS file system. When Rufus has finished, you can check the USB drive with `lsblk -f`

Comment: The sha256 hash looked ok, it matches the published hash.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)